# Adding CSS to layout file rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I have created a layout file as _navigation.html.erb in which I have my navigation bar code . I want to add background color to my nav bar for that I am using $navbar-default-bg:red; in bootstrap.scss file but nothing is happening why?

Comment: Can you point to the Bootstrap documentation that lists the variable names, so I can compare that to what you chose for the background color? Also, can you share your code - it could be your CSS doesn't conform to the BS specification.

Comment: Or you define the variable too late in your `scss`. You really need to share the code for us to help you.